# CSV file not downloading in android 13 pixel Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-13

I am downloading .csv file from server and save it in download folder. My code working in lower version except android 13. There are no permission asking before download. i think as per document no permission required for .csv file.Downloading shows success but not to see the file in downloads.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';



import '../colors.dart';


class DownloadFileFromSever extends StatefulWidget {
  const DownloadFileFromSever({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DownloadFileFromSever> createState() => _DownloadFileFromSeverState();
}

class _DownloadFileFromSeverState extends State<DownloadFileFromSever> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      platform = TargetPlatform.android;
    } else {
      platform = TargetPlatform.iOS;
    }
    String path="https://sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv";
    checkdownload(path,
        ".csv");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  Container(
        child: Text("data"),
      ),
    );
  }


  late String _localPath;
  late bool _permissionReady;
  late TargetPlatform? platform;
  checkdownload(String url,String extension)async{

    _permissionReady = await _checkPermission();
    print("Downloading1");
    if (_permissionReady) {
      saveDc(url,extension);
    }else{
      print("Downloading2");
      saveDc(url,extension);
    }
  }
  _checkPermission2(String url,String extension) async {

      // crap.
      print("False");
     final result= await Permission.photos.request();
      if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        final result = await Permission.storage.request();

        if (result == PermissionStatus.denied) {
          print("denied");
          saveDc(url,extension);
        }else{
          print("else");
          saveDc(url,extension);
        }

      }



  }

  saveDc(String url,String extension)async{
    await _prepareSaveDir();
    print("Downloading");
    try {
      String path="$_localPath/filename$extension";
      await Dio().download(url,
          path);
      print("Download Completed.");
      print("Download ${path}");
      OpenFile.open(path);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Download Failed.\n\n" + e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _checkPermission() async {
    print("platform1");
    if (platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      print("platform2");
      final status = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        print("granted");
        final result = await Permission.storage.request();
        if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        print("grantedelse");
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<void> _prepareSaveDir() async {
    _localPath = (await _findLocalPath())!;
    print("_localPath");
    print(_localPath);
    final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    if (!hasExisted) {
      savedDir.create();
    }
  }

  Future<String?> _findLocalPath() async {
    if (platform == TargetPlatform.android) {

   //   Directory? directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Directory? directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
      // Put file in global download folder, if for an unknown reason it didn't exist, we fallback
      // ignore: avoid_slow_async_io
   //   if (!await directory.exists()) directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      return  directory!.path;
    } else {
      var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      return '${directory.path}${Platform.pathSeparator}Download';
    }
  }
  double progress = 0;

  bool didDownloadPDF = false;
  String progressString = 'File has not been downloaded yet.';
  void updateProgress(done, total) {
    progress = done / total;
    setState(() {
      if (progress >= 1) {
        progressString = '✅ File has finished downloading. Try opening the file.';
        didDownloadPDF = true;
      } else {
        progressString = 'Download progress: ' + (progress * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + '% done.';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I have given my code.Thanks in advance